# So i am not able to create a calculated column for a table in mySQL, it says calculated columns cannot be calculated from calculated columns

Tags: mariadb, calculated-columns, mariadb-10.1

I am trying to create a calculated column but it shows error for the total_value column as it cannot be created from an calculated column vat_value...
Is there a way around it, I desperately need those two columns in the  table.
Thanks,

```
create table purchase(
invoice_num varchar(8),
product_id varchar(10),
product_name varchar(50),
supplier_name varchar(30),
gstn int(16),
vat_num varchar(12),
ph_num int(10),
quantity decimal(12,3),
unit varchar(3),
in_out char(1),
tax_value decimal(12,2),
gst_percent int(2),
igst decimal(12,2),
cgst decimal(12,2),
sgst decimal(12,2),
unloading int(8),
fare int(8),
vat_percent int(2),
vat_value decimal(8,3) as ((tax_value*vat_percent)/100) persistent,
total_value decimal(12,2) as (tax_value+igst+cgst+sgst+unloading+fare+vat_value)    
);
```

Comment: What is your MySQL version ? Run `Select VERSION();` and report the result of this query into the question. Generated Columns support was added only after MySQL version 5.7 and onwards.

Comment: 10.1.38 Maria-DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not refer one calculated column in definition of others.

One workaround can be, you refactor formula for total_value as below -

```
total_value decimal(12,2) as (tax_value+igst+cgst+sgst+unloading+fare+((tax_value*vat_percent)/100))
```

Comment: this works actually, Now I can use both columns without referring to the calculated column,

Comment: Glad to help!! Thank you for confirming.